# Calling Excel macro through from VB script having input box

Tags: vbscript

One excel macro is there which is having one variable getting value from Input box

```
  mysheet = Application.InputBox("Sheet To upload", "", ActiveSheet.Name)
  Sheets(mysheet).Activate
```

This macro i am executing using vb script. On executing vb script, system will stop once it displays input box (with default value i.e. is my active sheet name). Is there method where system will automatically accept/suppress this 'Ok' button in Input Box and proceed with default box.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Do you mean - system will show the input box with default values and it should automatically accept 'OK' and then proceed? What is the purpose of showing the input box then? You can use the default value and not show the input box at all...

Comment: i know.. but this macro what i am calling is not mine.. this is external excel macro on which i have no control... i can't change it.. :(